# Google Cloud Platform Windows Server 2012 activation

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, activation

I have a GCP instance based on Windows Server 2012 R2. Windows was activated from the start but a week ago apears like not activated. How can i fix this issue? I don't have high level support that i can use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running a `GCP free tier` according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier).

In any case, like normal usage of Windows the use of the software have cost. I would recommend you to review the specifications you need, and estimate the cost it would have to run your VM on a payment model. Take a look at [this calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator), it will help you in your estimation.

In addition Google Cloud Platform offers you significant discounts if you make the commitment to use the same type of VM and/or software for a long period of time. You can see the details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts).

Getting back to your answer is not an issue, it's just the normal limitation of the free trial.